# A VB.Net function could not execute by a GridViewCommandEventArgs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am developing an ASP.Net Website. I used GridView to display some information which in the database. Moreover, I put a button on each row in the GridView and set the CommandName of the button.

In the web page:

> asp:Button ID="btnShip" runat="server"
>   CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Invoice_No") %>' CommandName="Ship"
>   Text="Ship" Visible="True"

And then I create a VB function to handle the GridViewCommandEventArgs of this GridView. This is the following coding:

> Protected Sub Purchase_Process_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object,
>   ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
>
> If e.CommandName = "Ship" Then .....

Basically, it should do something If I press the button with CommandName "Ship". However, it doesn't work.
I tried to create a empty webpage and then copy the code into that page. It was working fine for a little moment...

I also put a MsgBox() before the If statement and I found the function won't execute when I press the button in the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

check in the grid properties there should be Purchase_Process_RowCommand in the ASP code

```
   <asp:GridView ID="Purchase_Process" runat="server"
     OnRowCommand="Purchase_Process_RowCommand">
       <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Invoice" Text="Edit Information"
          CommandName="Invoice" CommandArgument=<%# Eval("Invoice_No") %> />
         </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </asp:GridView>
```